# GSON: MalformedJsonException when running the jar file (works fine in Eclipse)

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, org.json

This is my first post here, hope someone can help me on this because I can't understand what's wrong.

I have a java method that parses a JSON String

```
    public static String getFieldFrom(String field, String event) {
    try {
        JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(event);
        JsonObject  obj = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
        return obj.getAsJsonObject("from").get(field).getAsString();            
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error parsing field " + field + ": " + e);
    }       
    return "-1";
}
```

Where the event is the string, and field the field I'm interested in. The program works fine when running on eclipse. If I compile it as a jar and I try to run it I get an Exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3 path $
```

The JSON string that's being processed is the same, this one (looks valid to me):

```
{"event": "message", "id": "00000000b0a2a54e1a01000000000000d", "flags": 258, "fwd_from": {"id": "$01000000428d8006442ef91f3ed48e27", "peer_type": "user", "peer_id": 109088066, "print_name": "Sample_Name", "flags": 1, "first_name": "Name", "last_name": "Sample", "username": "sampleuser"}, "fwd_date": 1522850949, "from": {"id": "$050023200b0a234e82865474b11fd9cd", "peer_type": "channel", "peer_id": 123232323, "print_name": "ChnNameTest", "flags": 19609, "title": "ChnNameTest", "participants_count": 0, "admins_count": 0, "kicked_count": 0}, "to": {"id": "$011200000b0a2a54e812345674b47fd9cd", "peer_type": "channel", "peer_id": 1319412121236, "print_name": "ChnNameTest", "flags": 196609, "title": "ChnNameTest", "participants_count": 0, "admins_count": 0, "kicked_count": 0}, "out": true, "unread": false, "service": false, "date": 1522850949, "text": "This is the message text"}
```

I'm trying to get the "id" field, under "from" object. I've also tried with another library (org.json) but the behavior is the same. Again, if I run the code on eclipse it's working.
I really don't know what to try... Hope someone can help me!
Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
The problem seems to be related with the string passed. So this is the piece of code that reads the stdout of a script i'm calling (that sends back json text).

```
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
    int c;
    char ca;
    String line="";
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) { //Read stdout char by char
          ca=(char)c;
          if(ca=='\n' || ca=='\r') { //Got a line
            if(line.contains("{\"event\":")) {  
                System.out.println(getFieldFrom("id",line)));
            }                   
            line="";
          }else {
            line=line+ca;
          }
      }
      in.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually getting the same intended JSON file when running your jar (from what I assume to be command-line)?

Comment: Yes. The JSON String you see there was printed in catch clause

Comment: I'm not too familiar with GSON anymore, but maybe that `$` character is the issue... Not sure how the leniency setting of the `JsonReader` might differ between running from your IDE and command-line, but that might be the key for you to debug this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mena Unfortunately no luck. Removing $ didn't helped

Comment: No problems. Hopefully someone else will have a better clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
        String json="{\"event\": \"message\", \"id\": \"00000000b0a2a54e1a01000000000000d\", \"flags\": 258, \"fwd_from\": {\"id\": \"$01000000428d8006442ef91f3ed48e27\", \"peer_type\": \"user\", \"peer_id\": 109088066, \"print_name\": \"Sample_Name\", \"flags\": 1, \"first_name\": \"Name\", \"last_name\": \"Sample\", \"username\": \"sampleuser\"}, \"fwd_date\": 1522850949, \"from\": {\"id\": \"$050023200b0a234e82865474b11fd9cd\", \"peer_type\": \"channel\", \"peer_id\": 123232323, \"print_name\": \"ChnNameTest\", \"flags\": 19609, \"title\": \"ChnNameTest\", \"participants_count\": 0, \"admins_count\": 0, \"kicked_count\": 0}, \"to\": {\"id\": \"$011200000b0a2a54e812345674b47fd9cd\", \"peer_type\": \"channel\", \"peer_id\": 1319412121236, \"print_name\": \"ChnNameTest\", \"flags\": 196609, \"title\": \"ChnNameTest\", \"participants_count\": 0, \"admins_count\": 0, \"kicked_count\": 0}, \"out\": true, \"unread\": false, \"service\": false, \"date\": 1522850949, \"text\": \"This is the message text\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
    String str = obj.getAsJsonObject("from").get("id").getAsString();
    System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

`$050023200b0a234e82865474b11fd9cd`

Comment: Thank you. If I specify JSON as String inside the code is working for me too. If I get the String from stdout it doesn't. I copied both strings and they look the same. There may be some invisible char somewhere?

Comment: Can you check doing this -
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();`

Comment: `Error parsing field id: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed.
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed.
 at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:861)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:854)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)
 at base.CliServer.getFieldFrom(CliServer.java:123)
 at base.CliServer.messageListener(CliServer.java:41)
 at base.Main.main(Main.java:6)`
It still cannot parse the JSON String

Comment: One last thing, can you try doing the following-
`event=event.trim();
JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(event, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
`

Comment: That solved the issue! event.trim shows an hidden char at the start of the string. Deleting that char makes the JSON valid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nephilim !

Solved it by doing:

```
event=event.trim();
event=event.replace("[K","");
```

After `event.trim();` the string has a "[K" at start which was not visible before. After removing that "[K" everything works!
It was probably some hiddend char that trim "extended".